# Common values in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays -

```
$x = [['email' => 'abc@gmail.com', 'id' => [1,2,3]],
      ['email' => 'xyz@gmail.com', 'id' => [4,5]]]
$y = ['email' => 'abc@gmail.com']
```

I have to return the common email in both the sets along with the ids in `$x` array.

The output should be -

```
$z = [['email' => 'abc@gmail.com', 'id' => [1,2,3]]
```

How to do it? `array_intersect`? But for `array_intersect` both arrays should have same number of keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it in traditional way by using foreach loop:

```
$x = [
    ['email' => 'abc@gmail.com', 'id' => [1, 2, 3]],
    ['email' => 'xyz@gmail.com', 'id' => [4, 5]]
];
$y = array('email' => 'abc@gmail.com');

$z = array();

foreach($x as $arr){
    if(in_array($arr['email'],$y) !== false){
        $z[] = $arr;
    }
}

print_r($z);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => abc@gmail.com
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the same. Just wanted to know if there is any other efficient way of doing this.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter()` with an anonymous function, passing to it a *needle* value by `use` directive:

```
$x = [
  ['email' => 'abc@gmail.com', 'id' => [1,2,3]],
  ['email' => 'xyz@gmail.com', 'id' => [4,5]]
];

$y = ['email' => 'abc@gmail.com'];

$matched = array_filter($x, function($item) use($y) {
  return $item['email'] === $y['email'];
});
```

Comment: searched email is a query result. So i think , I would have to use global.

Comment: @maggs Oh, it is possible to use outer variables in anonymous functions, I've updated my answer. Don't forget to mark and up-vote my answer if you prefer use it. Thanks!